# ¿Cómo borrar todo el texto?

Tags: javascript

Este código selecciona un código para ti y otro al azar, **el mayor número gana**. Si ganaste, te muestra un texto creado con `createTextNode`. Luego con `removeChild` elimino el texto en el `else{}`. El problema es que sí gano 2 veces seguidas no me elimina el texto anterior. ¿Cómo hago para que, aunque haya ganado **me muestre el texto una sola vez**?

***PD: Mi idea es hacerlo con un contador de los clicks, osea si cliquea por segunda vez, le borra el texto y añade el nuevo si gana.***

```js
function minumero() {

 var tunumero = Math.floor((Math.random() + 1) * 10);
 tunumero = parseInt(tunumero);

 var ainumero = Math.floor((Math.random() +1) * 10);
 ainumero = parseInt(ainumero);

 document.getElementById("tu").innerHTML = tunumero;
 document.getElementById("bingotu").style.visibility = "visible";
 document.getElementById("ait").innerHTML = ainumero;
 document.getElementById("bingoai").style.visibility = "visible";
 var texto = "";

 if(tunumero > ainumero) {
  document.getElementById("ganador").style.visibility = "visible";
  var divcreador = document.createElement('I');
  texto = "Has ganado contra la máquina!";
  var textoganador = document.createTextNode(texto);
  //textoganador.setAttribute("id", "textoganador");
  divcreador.appendChild(textoganador);
  document.getElementById("ganador").appendChild(divcreador);
 }
 else {

  var ilista = document.getElementById("ganador");
  while (ilista.firstChild) {
   // FIRST CHILD EL PRIMERO ELEMENTO
   // ELIMINAR TODOS LOS ELEMENTOS ( CREARE UN CONTADOR PARA EL BOTON Y BORRAR INMEDIATAMENTE)
   ilista.removeChild(ilista.childNodes[0]);
  }
 }
}
```

```css
#ai {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="learn.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title>JS Bin</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="ai">
    <center><b>Loteria del numero</b></center>
    
    <center><p>En qué consiste?</p></center>
    <center><p>Presiona el boton para obtener un número al azar, y la máquina realizará lo mismo, el <b style="color: red;">MAYOR NÚMERO</b>, será el ganador !</p></center>
    <center><input type="button" onclick="minumero()" value="MI NUMERO"></center>
    <hr></hr>
    <b id="bingotu" style="visibility: hidden;"> Tu numero es: <i id="tu"></i></b><hr></hr>
    <b id="bingoai" style="visibility: hidden;"> El numero de la maquina es: <i id="ait"></i></b>
    <hr></hr>
    <b style="visibility: hidden;"id="ganador"></b>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En vez de añadir nodos de texto, no te conviene poner un texto fijo en el HTML y cambiar la visibilidad del elemento según gane o pierda?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es al principio de tu función siempre vacía el texto de `document.getElementById('ganador').innerHTML = '';`

Comment: Si mariano , pero yo quiero saber de esta forma algo más compleja

Comment: Que sea compleja no quiere decir que este bien hecha

Answer (score 1):

Hice una recreación del juego, a mi manera, porque veo varios errores de concepto.

- En tu versión, se generan dos números aleatorios. En mi versión, el usuario tiene que ingresar el número, y luego se tiene que comparar con el número que genera la computadora. No tiene sentido que la computadora compita contra sí misma.
- En tu versión genera números entre 10 y 20. En mi versión solo genera del 0 al 9. No tiene sentido que el primer dígito sea siempre 1.

Para convertir un *string* en número, solo hay que poner un `+` al principio, de la siguiente manera:

```
var cant=+veces_ganadas.innerHTML
```

El campo de ***veces ganadas***, se lo agregué porque se repetía el texto cada vez que se ganaba, y me pareció buena idea que eso sea un valor numérico.

La siguiente línea valida que el texto ingresado, sea efectivamente un número de 1 dígito. Es decir, funciona como validador. Si no se cumple la condición, cambia por un 4.

```
if( !(tuyo>=0&tuyo<10) | tuyo.length==0 )
```

Lo siguiente, es un condicional en una sola línea, `?`. Esto cambia el valor de veces ganadas. Si `tuyo` es mayor a `ai` (número de la compu), aumenta en `1` las veces seguidas ganadas, y de lo contrario se pone en `0` nuevamente.

```
veces_ganadas.innerHTML=tuyo>ai?cant+1:0
```

El truco para ganar la mayor cantidad de veces, es poner siempre 9, pero si son iguales, el jugador pierde.

Código final:

```js
function generar_jugada() {

  var cant=+veces_ganadas.innerHTML
  var tuyo=ingresa.value
  if( !(tuyo>=0&tuyo<10) | tuyo.length==0 )
  {
    tuyo=4
    ingresa.value=tuyo
  }
  else
  {
    tuyo=+tuyo
  }
  var ai=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
  document.getElementById("compu").innerHTML=ai
  veces_ganadas.innerHTML=tuyo>ai?cant+1:0
}
```

```html
<p>
<input type="button" onclick="generar_jugada()" value="Generar jugada"> <a id="bingotu"> Tuyo: <input id="ingresa"></input></a>
</p>
<p>
<a> Computadora: <i id="compu"></i></a>
</p>
<div>Ganaste <a id="veces_ganadas">0</a> veces seguidas.</div>
```